# New Firebase Auth does not work

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

long time user. Went to create a new app with the new console. Working on localhost. Added localhost to Authorized domains which I have done a hundred time. Not allowing access. Asking me to add domain. You having launch issues?

Comment: Did you specify the port as well - will need 'localhost:5000' or similar

Comment: Yes. If you try and add the port is strips it out.

Comment: Shouldn't strip it out. Are you editing on the Google Developer console? https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apis/credentials/ - that's the best place to check the API key.

Comment: That's not the problem. When we redeploy old apps on the legacy issue they no longer work. The only thing we have done is upgrade them to the new console.

Answer (score 0):

When I migrated, Google created a new OAuth client ID for me with a new secret key etc. The new client ID had 3 authorized javascript origins:

```
http://localhost
http://localhost:5000
<my project's URL>
```

I had to manually update my Firebase project with the new client ID/secret.  To do this, I logged into my project in the new Firebase console, clicked 'Auth' in the lefthand menu, selected the 'Sign In Method' tab, then Google, then Web SDK Configuration.

[image]

After that, it worked.